# $emit does not add event vue3

Tags: javascript, events, vuejs3, vue3-openlayers

I have the following element, which listens on the `drawend` event.

```js
<ol-interaction-draw
  ref="test"
  @drawend="drawend"
>
```

When `drawend` is triggered normally by the element itself, `event` is passed to the function:

```js
drawend(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

But when I try to trigger it manually, `event` is `undefined`.

```js
test = ref(null);
test.$emit("drawend");
```

How can I emit the event correctly?

Answer (score 1):

When you call an event like this:

```
<ol-interaction-draw
  ref="test"
  @drawend="drawend"
>
```

in fact, you are calling:

```
<ol-interaction-draw
  ref="test"
  @drawend="$emit('drawend', $event)"
>
```

Where $emit has a second parameter - the event object or any other data.

Try to do this, for example, and you will see for yourself what will be transferred to the draw end:

```
test = ref(null);
test.$emit("drawend", {}); // => where {} is a custom object that is passed to the "drawend" trigger
```

Comment: But how can I access the $event as if drawend was triggered by the element itself when emitting drawend manually?